# Git repository cloning with GitPython - repository not found Authentication Failed

Tags: clone, gitpython

I am trying to clone private repository using Python. I am using Git Python package to clone the repository but I am getting an error:

> Error :
>    GitCommandError: 'git clone -v https://github.mit.edu/mitx/content-mit-1690rgit edxcourse' returned exit status 128: Cloning into 'edxcourse'...
>   remote Repository not found.
>   fatal : Authentication failed for 'https://github.mit.edu/mitx/content-mit-1690.r.git/'

However I am a member of this repository and I have access to the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository which I was trying to Clone is a secured repo. So I need to establish a secure ssh authentication connection. and then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, gitpython merely returns an error it received from the git executable it envoked.

If you call `git clone -v https://github.mit.edu/mitx/content-mit-1690rgit` on the commandline, you will receive a similar error, indicating something might be wrong with your URL. Possibly it is the `rgit` extension, which might be a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the devs can confirm this as I have only been playing around with Git-Python for the last few hours.

When cloning over http(s) it seems to rely on the `.netrc` file rather than asking for auth like the Git CLI client would.

```
cat > ${HOME}/.netrc < EOF
machine github.mit.edu
login <username>
password <password>
EOF

chmod 600 ${HOME}/.netrc
```

If you're on Windows, that works via Cygwin too.